# T-SQL Different Comparison in WHERE Clause Using CASE

Tags: t-sql, case, where-clause

I wanted to do different comparison expression in where clause, but it keep prompt me invalid syntax. The reason i want to use this because i wanted to enforce the evaluation according to the Type. If i use ((t1.Amount <= @valueB) OR (t1.Type IN (1) AND t1.Amount > 0 AND @valueB < 0)) , it seems to be not expression i trying to impose into my query. If first evaluation success, i would not want the following to execute, however OR in sql is not short-circuit operator.

```
DECLARE @name AS VARCHAR(200) = 'super'
DECLARE @valueA AS INT = 1 -- Can be 1 or 2
DECLARE @valueB AS DECIMAL = 0.5

SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 t1 WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE t1.Name = @name
AND 
CASE WHEN t1.Type = 1 THEN (t1.Amount > 0 AND @valueB < 0)
          ELSE (t1.Amount <= @valueB)
END
```

Comment: You can't use case like this. It's not a flow control, it's an expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use it that way.

**TRY THIS**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 t1 WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE t1.Name = @name AND 
((t1.Type = 1 AND t1.Amount > 0 AND @valueB < 0)
OR (t1.Amount <= @valueB))
```

If could elaborate further what you are trying to achieve , I'll be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Zohar Peled's comment rightly points out that `CASE` is an expression in T-SQL, it is not a flow-of-control statement.

What you are trying to do is:

```
IF <expression_A> = <value_A> 
THEN <apply_condition_B> 
ELSE <apply_condition_C>
```

To achieve the following in SQL, you'd need to write it out using Boolean logic using the `AND` and `OR` operators as:

```
( 
    ( <expression_A> =      <value_A> AND <apply_condition_B> ) 
 OR ( <expression_A> is not <value_A> AND <apply_condition_C> ) 
)
```

The first `AND` that comes before `<apply_condition_B>` acts like the `THEN` keyword, while the combination of the `OR` and the second `AND` act like the `ELSE` keyword.

Taking your query into consideration, we get the following mapping:

```
<expression_A>       = t1.Type 
<value_A>            = 1 
<apply_condition_B>  = (t1.Amount > 0 AND @valueB < 0) 
<apply_condition_C>  = (t1.Amount <= @valueB)
```

Putting that into query form would give us:

```
WHERE t1.Name = @name
AND 
( 
    ( t1.Type  = 1 AND (t1.Amount > 0 AND @valueB < 0) ) 
 OR ( t1.Type != 1 AND (t1.Amount <= @valueB)          ) 
) 
-- Note - this is not fully complete, as it assumes t1.Type is not NULL
```

The above is a simple rewrite of your intended logic. However, do note that SQL operates on [three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#Application_in_SQL) which means that `t1.Type` can be 1, it can be a value other than 1, or it can be `NULL`. The above code fragment handles only two of these 3 possibilities. To correctly handle `t1.Type` being `NULL` you can use the `COALESCE()` function to return a specified value (zero, below) in case it is `NULL`:

```
WHERE t1.Name = @name
AND 
( 
    (          t1.Type      = 1 AND (t1.Amount > 0 AND @valueB < 0) ) 
 OR ( COALESCE(t1.Type, 0) != 1 AND (t1.Amount <= @valueB)          ) 
)
```

**Tip**: Before using this sort of construct directly in your actual query, I'd suggest you play around with it using simpler sample data to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @name AS VARCHAR(200) = 'super'
DECLARE @valueA AS INT = 1 -- Can be 1 or 2
DECLARE @valueB AS DECIMAL = 0.5

SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1 t1 WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE t1.NAME = @name
AND (t1.Type = 1 AND (t1.Amount > 0 AND @valueB < 0)
    OR t1.Type <> 1 AND (t1.Amount <= @valueB))

GO
```

OR Use Dynamic SQL if you feel like it

```
DECLARE @name AS VARCHAR(200) = 'super'
DECLARE @valueA AS INT = 1 -- Can be 1 or 2
DECLARE @valueB AS DECIMAL = 0.5
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Type INT

SELECT TOP 1 @Type = t1.Type
FROM TABLE_1 t1 WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE t1.NAME = @name

SET @SQL = 'SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1 t1 WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE t1.NAME = @name'
SET @SQL = CASE 
        WHEN @Type = 1
            THEN @SQL + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + '   AND (t1.Amount > 0 AND @valueB < 0)'
        ELSE @SQL + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + '   AND (t1.Amount <= @valueB)'
        END

--PRINT @SQL

EXEC (@SQL)
GO
```